# .NET LiveCharts, Performance Issues with real-time data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, livecharts

I am using [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/) for my WPF app and am currently facing an issue with performance when plotting multiple `LineSeries`/`GLineSeries` with real-time data. Here's a GIF showing what's happening:

[image: livecharts]

Although it's subtle, my issue with this graph is that it noticeably "jumps" ahead quite often and does not appear "smooth" visually.

I plotted the same data (10 lines with 400 points each) with OxyPlot:

[image: oxyplot]

And although it is not ideal as well, it seems to generate a nicer "flow" of data.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
            {
                field = newValue;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject, IDataListener
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SignalGraphViewModel> SignalGraphs { get; }

        private int _maxSeriesPoints = 400;

        public SeriesCollection Series { get; set;  }
        public CartesianChart Chart { get; set; }
        public int NChannels { get; set; }

        private bool _isReading = false;
        public bool IsReading {
            get => _isReading;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isReading, value);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel(int nChannels)
        {
            NChannels = nChannels;
            SignalGraphs = new ObservableCollection<SignalGraphViewModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nChannels; i++)
            {
                SignalGraphs.Add(new SignalGraphViewModel(i));
            }

            Series = new SeriesCollection();

            for (var i = 0; i < NChannels; i++)
            {
                var series = new GLineSeries
                {
                    Values = new GearedValues<double>(),
                    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    PointGeometry = null
                };
                Series.Add(series);
            }

            Chart = new CartesianChart
            {
                DisableAnimations = true,
                DataTooltip = null,
                Hoverable = false,
                Zoom = ZoomingOptions.None,
                Series = Series                
            };
        }

        public void Update(EEGSamples samples)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {
                UpdateChart(samples);
            });
        }

        private void UpdateChart(EEGSamples samples)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (var i = 0; i < NChannels; i++)
            {
                var channelSamples = samples.Data.Select(d => (object)(d.Measurements[i] + i * 3000)).AsGearedValues();
                Chart.Series[i].Values.AddRange(channelSamples);

                for (var j = Chart.Series[i].Values.Count; j > _maxSeriesPoints; j--)
                {
                    Chart.Series[i].Values.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

where `Update` method gets called every 50 milliseconds with 6 data points for each line.

Am I expecting too much? Is this too heavy of a scenario to be handled flawlessly in the UI?

Comment: Sorry to write this non-informative comment, but: The graphics freaks me out. I'd suggfest not to make animated gif.

Comment: Yes, I can see why you're saying that. I just thought that without visualizing it, it would be impossible to describe what's happening.